# why does "numberOrRowsInSection" get called mid-way through "viewDidLoad"?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, viewdidload

BACKGROUND:

1. Within my viewDidLoad I am loading test calendar data (via EventKit) to the iPhone.  I am noting that when the table view loads the first time it does not see this data.
2. When I look at the sequence of log messages I see that it goes something like this:

Logging here:

```
[AppointmentListController viewDidLoad] Starting
[AppointmentListController populateTestData] Populating the test data now
[AppointmentListController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] Number of rows = 0
[AppointmentListController viewDidLoad] Loading the existing calendar events
[AppointmentListController viewDidLoad] Ending
```

QUESTION(S)

- Why does "numberOrRowsInSection" get called mid-way through "viewDidLoad"?   I ask this as this is what I am seeing (is this what should happen?).
- If this is normal that you can't be sure viewDidLoad will complete before numberOrRowsInSection, then this would imply you need a "[self.tableView reloadData]" at the end of your "viewDidLoad" method to make sure it does update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method is likely called because you configured something on your table view (maybed you've added it to its superview) and it therefor needed to know its metrics. It does not magically trigger by itself out of the blue. Either make sure to prepare your data before you configure the UI elements or call `reloadData` near the end, but I'd find the former to be "cleaner".

Comment: ok DarkDust - it's ok to setup UI elements in the "viewDidLoad" method though isn't it?  In which case I think you're say within "viewDidLoad" do load your data first before hitting the UI elements configuration lines - did I understand you correctly here?

Comment: Yes, setting up and configuring UI elements in `viewDidLoad` is perfectly fine. And yes, you've understood that correct: inside the `viewDidLoad` method first set up the non-UI data (as far as they don't rely on data from UI elements), and then set up the UI elements. This way you don't need to call `reloadData` yourself, it will be called at a time convenient to the table view and thus prevents unnecessary method calls.

Comment: I was creating viewmode inside viewDidLoad. But it called the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection before that and, viewmodel is nil. App crashed.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal....

```
Call [self.tableView reloadData]
```

; at the end of viewdidload